# How to get Docker images to use my transparent/intercept squid on the host without touching Docker images?

Tags: networking, proxy, iptables, squid, apt-cacher-ng

I have a squid instance running on my server which is connected to `192.168.178.0/24` through `eth0` with `192.168.178.26` and serves as gateway for the LAN `192.168.179.0/24` through `p18p1` with `192.168.179.1`. I use

```
sudo iptables -t nat --append squid --match owner ! --uid-owner 171 -p tcp --dport 80 --jump DNAT --to 192.168.178.26:3128
sudo iptables -t nat --append PREROUTING -i p18p1 ! -s 192.168.179.1 -p tcp --dport 80 --jump DNAT --to 192.168.178.26:3128
sudo iptables --append FORWARD -s 192.168.179.0/24 -d 192.168.179.1 -i p18p1 -o p18p1 -p tcp --dport 3128 --jump ACCEPT
```

to redirect traffic from the LAN and the gateway to squid which has a `url_rewrite_program` configured which then redirects requests for `.deb` packages to `192.168.178.26:3142` where `apt-cacher-ng` is listening and serving the request (171 is the ID of the `apt-cacher-ng` system user). This setup works well for the gateway and LAN clients running Ubuntu as well as VirtualBox machines with NAT or bridge networks. However not for Docker, no matter which `--network` mode is specified (I guess one can expect that since the virtualization is different from VirtualBox).

I tried

```
sudo iptables -t nat --append squid --match owner ! --uid-owner 171 -p tcp --dport 80 --jump DNAT --to 192.168.178.26:3128
sudo iptables -t nat --append PREROUTING -i docker0 ! -s 172.17.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 --jump DNAT --to 192.168.178.26:3128
sudo iptables --append FORWARD -s 172.17.0.0/16 -d 172.17.0.1 -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp --dport 3128 --jump ACCEPT
```

but that has no effect (my test is `sudo docker run -it --network="bridge" ubuntu:zesty` and inside docker I run `apt-get update && apt-get install --yes gcc`)

So, just to make sure: I don't want to run squid inside Docker. It's not a bad idea, but squid is working fine on the host and I don't want to touch this working system. Changing the Docker images (I assume I could simply add a few `iptables` statements to the startup routine) is not an option because they should still be usable on remote CI services.

I'm using `squid` SQUID_4_0_16-455-gc672a58b2 installed from source on Ubuntu 17.04.